# background duplication issue on mobile size

Tags: php, html, css

every time I scale the size of the browser to a mobile size, the head and the body gets the same background twice. I assume the problem is with the css, therefore I attach the part of the css:

> also my header is an a PHP include.

```
html, body{
    background:url('background.jpg') center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

if anyone can see where the problem is, that could be great.

thanks.

Comment: You set the property `background` for both, html **and** body but that shouldn't be the problem. More code is needed.

Comment: no more code that related to the background.

Comment: Do you have a margin on the body? That could explain it...

Comment: @AriEfron **all** html elements 'mess' with the body of the webpage. So, if we should help you, you need to post the html **structure** and the CSS of it. We can't see if you only provide a little piece of your page.